# How to enable classic logon prompt instead of welcome screen in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to have Windows 7 show the classic logon prompt instead of the welcome screen? I'd prefer to have the users type in their username/password as opposed to it showing all the users' names/icons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Type secpol.msc in Start Menu Search Bar and hit Enter. This will open the Local Security Policy editor.
>   Navigate to `Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options`.

[image]

> Now on RHS, look for `Interactive Logon: Do not display last username`
>   Rt click on it and open its Properties.
>   Set it to Enabled > Apply.

[image]

[source](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t47.html)

Comment: @joe - FYI, your images are broken.

Comment: is it not visible ?

Comment: nope, not visible. maybe you have some weird 'hotlink prevention' script on your site? or maybe you have to be logged in to view the images?