# Windows 7 logon - avoid clicking user icon

Tags: windows, windows-7

After installing a recent Windows 7 update, suddenly I have an additional annoying step before I can log in. It shows a list of user accounts (mine is the only 1), and I have to click the little icon above my username, and only then am I brought to the actual logon screen.

How do I skip that initial click step? I want to be taken straight to the logon screen like I had it before, in which my username is prepopulated and I just have to enter a password. How can I do this?

Comment: [How to enable classic logon prompt instead of welcome screen in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/69676/how-to-enable-classic-logon-prompt-instead-of-welcome-screen-in-windows-7/) meets you halfway. You don't need to mouse the user icon, but you do have to type the username every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this first:
Start > Control Panel > User Accounts > Change the Way Users Log On or Off
disable 'Use Welcome Screen'

Try this second:
 - Start -> Run -> Regedit (ENTER)

browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Set the 'DefaultDomainName' to be your computers name (or leave it blank)
Set 'DefaultUserName' to your user name

Comment: "Change the Way Users Log On or Off" does not show up on my Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

its possible through a simple editing in **Group Policy**.

**Computer Configuration > Windows settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options**

From here we need enable the following policy.

**Interactive Logon: Do not display last user namme**

If u want more support pls click on the following link.

http://wp.me/p439jR-43

Answer (score 0):

You can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select your user. If you have a password you will be asked next for it, so you need your keyboard anyway. If you don't have a password set you'll get logged in right away.