# Windows 7: Is there any way to set classic logon screen but remembering the last username?

Tags: windows-7, login

I would like to have some **logon screen** like this one on my **Windows 7 Ultimate**:

[image: Win7 Classic Logon]

I have only found methods to change the logon screen, but **removing the last username** like in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/69676/how-to-enable-classic-logon-prompt-instead-of-welcome-screen-in-windows-7) .

I want to **keep the last username**. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you forget the thread ?

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like.

Comment: Windows remembering the last username, is a fundamental element of `Interactive Logon`, it literally is the one of the major reasons the logon is considered ["interactive"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6aaef13d-ccd6-44ed-b128-1c216ae0e211/what-is-interactive-logon?forum=itproxpsp).